# Script for running c++ inside Notepad++ without extra white line

Tags: c++, notepad++

I have a C++ script as follows:

```
NPP_SAVE
cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)
g++ -o "$(NAME_PART).exe" "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
"$(NAME_PART).exe"
```

I try to compile my first C++ programming, print `Hello, World`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << "Hello, World!";
  return 0;
}
```

However, I see a an extra white line
[image]

Question:

How to delete it?

It means as following:
[image]

Comment: mmm... why do you torture yourself and write and compile C++ in notepad++?

Comment: @paddy, This script is still good for C. :-)

Comment: @bolov ... I don't know anymore... :-(

Comment: do yourself a favor and use a propper IDE, preferably with native support for C++

Comment: Notepad++ is actually not bad for C++ editing.  (But I use Vim.)